# Install ServiceUser with deployment

Tags: maven, deployment, sling, user-management

I am currently planning to deploy required ServiceUsers with bundle. To do so I created a user with the Composum user manager which is shipped with sling10. Then I exported a package with my user and extracted in to put the folder structure in my maven project.

*myapp/ui/src/main/resources/jcr_root/home/users/system/myapp/cNmLYZeYn1j_2LP6vhlVl*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:rep="internal"
   jcr:primaryType="rep:SystemUser"
   jcr:uuid="ded83881-f468-31bf-8f31-5d34b4d08475"
   rep:authorizableId="myServiceUser"
   rep:principalName="myServiceUser"/>
```

The user should then be deployed with the Sling-Initial-Content configuration.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
            <artifactId>bnd-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>run-bnd</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bnd-process</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <bnd>Sling-Nodetypes: SLING-INF/nodetypes/nodetypes.cnd
                    Sling-Initial-Content: \
                    jcr_root/home/users/system/;overwrite:=true;uninstall:=true;path:=/home/users/system/,\
                    jcr_root/apps/myapp;overwrite:=true;uninstall:=true;path:=/apps/myapp,\
                    jcr_root/etc/myapp;overwrite:=true;uninstall:=true;path:=/etc/myapp,\
                    jcr_root/content/myapp;overwrite:=true;overwriteProperties:=true;uninstall:=false;path:=/content/myapp
                </bnd>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

My problem is that I am facing an error that I am not allowed to create a child node in /home/users/system/

> *ERROR* [Background Update ui (161)] org.apache.sling.jcr.contentloader.internal.BundleContentLoader Cannot load initial content for bundle ui : OakConstraint0001: /home/users/system[[rep:AuthorizableFolder]]: No matching definition found for child node cellular with effective type [sling:Folder]
>   javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: OakConstraint0001: /home/users/system[[rep:AuthorizableFolder]]: No matching definition found for child node cellular with effective type [sling:Folder]

After facing that issue I was researching in other projects how ServiceUsers are created. I found out that the slingshot sample application is using the provisioning model to create ServiceUsers. [sling-samples/slingshot/src/main/provisioning/model.txt](https://github.com/apache/sling-samples/blob/master/slingshot/src/main/provisioning/model.txt) The difference between my application and the slingshot is that the slingshot application will be installed with the initial startup of the sling-quickstart.jar. I am not sure if i can use the repository initialisation when deploying to an existing Sling instance.

Is there any recommended way to "deploy" ServiceUsers with the regular bundle?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having a specific bundle, which is whitelisted for the administrative resolver, to create all needed service users with the bundle activator. The privileges are deployed with the content of the project.

I thought about creating the service users with Ansible during the initial server setup. But Ansible is using the curl command to create the users, and I only found an example to create a regular user with this method.

I will update this when I found a better way to solve this issue.